# panel is on the right side (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

Somehow the panel got moved to the right side.  How do I move it back to the top?  I tried right clicking, dragging, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, @Adam's answer gave me the term that I needed to lead me to the answer, namely "Orientation".  Here's the solution:

- Start a terminal
- Type: `gconf-editor`
- Navigate to /apps/panel/toplevels/top_panel_screen0/orientation
- Double-click to bring up the "edit" dialog
- Change `right` to `top`

There is also a ... bottom_panel_screen0/orientation that can be changed as well... probably you want it at `bottom`.

Answer (score 0):

- right-click on panel
- choose "Properties"
- modify "Orientation" combo box as desired

Comment: I don't get Properties when I right click

Comment: For what its worth right click works on my Ubuntu 10.4 LTS.

Comment: It's too full of panel items... every time I click on it, it's on one of the items, not on the panel itself

Comment: Are you right-clicking on a part of the panel with no icons/text?

What do you see when you right-click?

...ah, nevermind, just saw your other answer. If my original answer helped, would you mind voting it up or marking it as the accepted answer? I'm dying for 10 points on superuser.com. :)